# XML parsing error: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: xml, podcast

Online validator throws error on url in my XML page. Here is affected string:

```
http://some.normal.url?params=id%2Cburst%2Cfactor%2Ccp&exp=907031
```

error is pointed at place of second equal sign exp **=** 907031.

I searched before, and according some posts equal sign is not allowed, but then how first equal sign passed, and link won't work if I urlquote it.

What can I do here to bypass this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ampersand is the problem. Ampersands in XML act as the start of an encoded character, so you need to encode the ampersand itself. E.g. `&amp;`.
Change your complete URL to this:
`http://some.normal.url?params=id%2Cburst%2Cfactor%2Ccp&amp;exp=907031`